# Complex form of Fourier Series

Tags: integration, reference-request, fourier-series, self-learning

So, the last part of the university syllabus in the chapter of Fourier Series is:

```
3.3 Half range sine and cosine Fourier series, Parsevel’s (without proof).
3.4 Orthogonal and Ortho-normal functions, Complex form of series.
3.5 Fourier Integral Representation.
```

I am done with orthogonal functions and orthogonal set of functions. I am ok with Parseval's identity. I can calculate half range sine and cosine series.

So what is left is two more topics:

Complex form of series

Fourier integral representation

**Can someone please tell me what they are?** *Possiblly point to beginner-level resources*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following would be of help (at least as a starter, for your reference request):

["Complex Form of Fourier Series"](http://www.math24.net/complex-form-of-fourier-series.html) (Math24.net), this page goes through the derivations and provides a worked example.  It also has quite a bit of explanation of what they are.

[This Youtube clip: "Lecture 4: Complex Form of Fourier Series Part 1 of 2"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yk1Q_rfY_B4), and the second part is [here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PBM5EXmiFQ)

[This Youtube clip: "Mod-03 Lec-29 Fourier Integral Representation of a Function"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sFOQo-YVUc), and [this Wolfram explanation and derivation of Fourier integral representations](http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/5/), also provide an explanation and derivations.

I hope this is some help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to understand complex Fourier series representation. Consider $L^2 [-\pi,\pi]$, the set of square integrable complex valued functions on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.  Define the inner product on this space: $$\langle u(x),v(x)\rangle=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} u(x)\overline{v(x)}dx.$$
In addition, we can define the norm: $$\|u(x)\|=\sqrt{\langle u(x),u(x) \rangle}$$
We ask, what is an orthonormal basis $S$ for $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ ? Recall orthonormal means that given two vectors $v_i,v_j$ in a set, $\langle v_i,v_j \rangle=\delta_{ij}$ where $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$ and $\delta_{ij}=0$ if $i \neq j$.  Consider: $$S=\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right\}\cup \left \{
\frac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}},\frac{e^{-inx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}:n\in\mathbb{N}
 \right \}.$$
Verify the set is orthonormal. 
Suppose $f(x)\in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ is arbitrary. We must show $f(x) \in \text{Span}(S)$.  That is we must find constants $\alpha_{0},\alpha_{n},\beta_{n} \in \mathbb{C}$ such that: $$f(x)=\frac{\alpha_{0}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\alpha_{n}e^{inx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+\frac{\beta_{n}e^{-inx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}}.$$  We can do this because since $S$ is orthonormal: $$\alpha_{0}=\left \langle
f(x),\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \right \rangle,\alpha_{n}=\left \langle
f(x),\frac{e^{inx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \right \rangle,\beta_{n}=\left \langle
f(x),\frac{e^{-inx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \right \rangle.$$ Verify why this is true. Also verify why the set $S$ is a linearly independent set. These inner products are the Complex Fourier Coefficients. It also worth noting that if we consider the partial sum: $$\widehat{f(x)}=\frac{\alpha_{0}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}{\frac{\alpha_{n}e^{inx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+\frac{\beta_{n}e^{-inx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}},$$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$, $\|f(x)-\widehat{f(x)}\| \rightarrow 0,$ which shows the Fourier sum approximates better and better for very large $N$. Parseval's identity here states:

$$\|f(x)\|^2=\langle f,f \rangle=\alpha^2_{0}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha^2_n+\beta^2_n.$$
This can be obtained by replacing the computed Fourier series for $f(x)$ into the components of $\langle f, f\rangle$ and using multilinearity of the inner product to simplify the result.